# MS Azure and Credit Card with Security Code

Tags: azure

We would try to start a new Azure Subscription using the Company credit card, but we can't proceed. It seem that Azure didn't accept the Credit Cards protected by "Security Code".

We are sure that our Credit Card is valid.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not Azure billing/payment inquiries

Comment: You are right, I would just know if someone else found the same issue